# What is the best time to use celebrity?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

**CELEBRITY VIP**:
Allows buyers to buy one of every product a level stocks.

What does this mean? Does the celebrity make people buy every product for a time? Until a product is finished? Until all products are finished?

What would be the best time to use celebrity for maximum efficiency?

Answer (score 4):

Celebrities send about 50 people to the desired floor, who then buy 1 of each tier of stock available.  So send them to any floor with at least 50 stock at all 3 tiers.

Comment: They are also useful for clearing out the last remaining stock quickly in a store with a long restock time.  That is, if there are just 30 tier 3 items left in a store with a 5-hour restock period, sending a Celebrity will empty that out more quickly so that you can start the restock.  It doesn't make full use of the Celebrity's buying influence, but this is helpful when you are about to be away from the game for a while and don't want to wait to start the restocking.